# Syncronizing mobile phone contacts with contacts from social networks

Tags: java, android, mobile, synchronization, social-networking

I retrieve a **JSON** list of contacts from a social network site. It contains `firstname, lastname, displayname, data1, data2`, etc...

What is the efficient way to quickly lookup my local phone contacts database and "match" them based on their name. Since there are `firstname, lastname` and `displayname` this can vary.
What do you think, how can the best match be achieved?

Also how do I make sure I don't parse for each JSON item the whole database I want to avoide having **JSON_COUNT** x **MOBILE COUNT** steps

**Edit**

Still looking for some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Jaro-Winkler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848807/optimizing-jaro-winkler-algorithm) algorithm is a way to accomplish this.